# export database to csv change some fields names

Tags: php, mysql, export, export-to-csv

I want to export my database to an csv file. I have this alrealdy:

```
$query=mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM table_name") or die("Problemas con la 
 conexión: ".mysqli_error($conexion));
 $variable_name = array();
 if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
      $variable_name[] = $row;
  }
 }
 header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.csv"');
 header('Pragma: no-cache');
 header('Expires: 0');
 $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
 fputcsv($output, array('col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6', 
 'col7', 'col8', 'col9', 'col10'));
  if (count($varible_name) > 0) {
    foreach($variable_name as $row) {
    fputcsv($output, $row);
   }
  }
 fclose($output);
```

This is working fine, but I just realice that one column has the id value an not the real value that is related to another table. The thing is that I want to replace the id numbers of that column with the real names of the values. Let's say that col3 has values of 1, 2,  or 4 and I want to replace those values with 'Column value for 1', 'Column value for 2', etc.
I try to join the tables but it joined the ids, so i still have the numbers an not the named values.

How can I do it? thank you

UPDATE.

Example of the table to export.

```
table1
id   name   job   payment   workshop
 1   susan  job1  yes       1
 2   mike   job2  yes       3
 3   bob    job3  no        2
 4   rob    job3  no        3

table2
id  workshop_name
1   cooking
2   talking
3   running
```

When I try to join both tables the cvs file was:

`id  name   job   payment   workshop
 1   susan  job1  yes       1           cooking
 2   mike   job2  yes       3           running
 3   bob    job3  no        2           talking
 4   rob    job3  no        3           running`

What I want is to replace the numbers in col workshop with the names form table2: cooking running talking. Maybe with a simple switch i can change the numbers with the names, but I don't know how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: Please share a sample of your data and the desired output

Comment: looking into the code colours.. i should say your code contains a parsing error or this question contains a copy paste error.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, yes i had a copy and paste error. Just fix it. But still need an answer